# looking for cloud service upload large files e.g. pdf of 60mb or high res images and create thumbnail

Tags: google-app-engine, image-processing, file-upload, amazon-s3, cloud

I'm looking for a cloud based service which will allow my customers to upload very high resolution and print pdfs (sometimes about 60mb), store the images and create low resolution images very quickly

I've started looking at Amazon S3 but know this doesn't do anything with the files uploaded and started looking at google app engine.

I did think about using dropbox core api but i think this is really for 1 to 1 users rather than hundreds of users daily.

Any suggestions for services would be great

Thanks
David

Answer (score 2):

have a look at google cloud storage:
https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage

there you can upload files up to 5 tb, and as many as you can pay.
it works perfectly with lots of users. you can use buckets or folders per user, its up to you.

also its possible to reach that files with an own domain,

apis are available for many languages as well

Comment: sounds like a good idea, is it easy to integrate with an uploader... like plupload?

Comment: it is easier to use the plain api, and it all depends how you would like to use, it, only from frontend, choose js plain api, from backend, with java and python its very easy, with go its easy and with php i dont know, if you choose from backend then you should be able to easy integrate it with uploaders like plpload